# Swift webView load content wrong Insets on iPhone XS

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I use code below to set contentInset of webView for show content full screen. It show beautiful on iPhoneX or iPhone older. Now when load app on iPhone XS or XS Max , content show not same iPhone X. Anyone help me? 
Thanks !!!

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
   mWebView.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
}
```

Images:
iPhone X
[image: iPhone X]

XS Max
[image: iPhone XS Max]

Comment: What happens on an iPhone X running iOS 12?

Comment: @AshleyMills iPhoneX on iOS 12 show beautiful. Only new iPhone show not good.